# Jmeter SQL testing

Tags: testing, jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing

### question 1:

how to load and stress test a query using jmeter without the help of any jsp page or action class?(i need to know by which test criteria we could decide that it is a good query).

### question 2:

how to forward a result set of a jdbc request as an input parameter to next jdbc request.
ex:

1. jdbc request1: you are having a stored procedure that returns the next primary key of a given table.
2. jdbc request2: an insert query to that table that takes the resulting primarykey from that stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1:**
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html

A set of "good queries" would be a set that would contain queries that would be a good representation of all the queries you expect will be run against your db in a production environment.

**Question 2:**
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor